# PostgreSQL foreign key references inherited table

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance

I am trying to simplify my code via inheritance. Here is what I have right now

```
DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC;

CREATE TABLE student(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   age INT
);

CREATE TABLE engineer(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   studentId INT REFERENCES student (id),
   friend INT REFERENCES student (id)
);

CREATE TABLE artist(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   studentId INT REFERENCES student (id),
   friend INT REFERENCES student (id)
);

INSERT INTO student (age) VALUES (20); --Trying to remove this
INSERT INTO student (age) VALUES (21); --Trying to remove this
INSERT INTO engineer (studentId) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO artist (studentId,friend) VALUES (2,1);
```

I don't want to have to type those two lines, therefore, I am using the below line

```
DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC;

CREATE TABLE student(
   studentId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   age INT
);

CREATE TABLE engineer(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   friend INT REFERENCES student (studentId)
) INHERITS (student);

CREATE TABLE artist(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   friend INT REFERENCES student (studentId)
) INHERITS (student);

INSERT INTO engineer (id,age) VALUES (DEFAULT,20);
INSERT INTO artist (id,age,friend) VALUES (DEFAULT,20,1);
```

But I get the following error.

```
psql:test.psql:45: ERROR:  insert or update on table "artist"     
violates foreign key constraint "artist_friend_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (friend)=(1) is not present in table "student".
```

Is this yet another limitation to add to the long list of Postgres issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Look at [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html)
Bottom Caveats section:

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes
>   (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply
>   to single tables, not to their inheritance children

Comment: *Darth Vader Voice* NOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooo

Comment: In facts, Postgres inheritance should be considered as a structural trait. Very useful because when a trait is modified, all the tables using it are updated as well.

Comment: @greg I don't speak Klingon =p care to dumb that down for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a workaround for this. I just moved the reference into the parent like so

```
DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC;

CREATE TABLE student(
   studentId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   age INT,
   friend INT REFERENCES student (studentId)
);

CREATE TABLE engineer(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
) INHERITS (student);

CREATE TABLE artist(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
) INHERITS (student);

INSERT INTO engineer (id,age) VALUES (DEFAULT,20);
INSERT INTO artist (id,age,friend) VALUES (DEFAULT,20,1);
```